# In R, how do I count unique values of a factor based on another factor?

Tags: r

I have data which could be described as...

```
factor1 <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5))
factor2 <- c("title1", "title1", "title2", "title2", "title3",
             "title4", "title4", "title4", "title4", "title5",
             "title6", "title6", "title6", "title6", "title6")

df <- data.frame(factor1, factor2)
```

...and what I want is a count of how many unique values in `factor2` occur at each level of `factor1`. So my expected output in this case would be:

```
A   3
B   2
C   1
```

What is the most efficient (because Shiny will later be involved) function to do this? My various attempts at `table` or `xtabs` or `aggregate` are being foiled by the fact that both columns are factors.

Comment: Actually `cbind` is making a character matrix, not a data.frame with factors. If you put it in a data.frame, being a factor doesn't make a difference: `table(unique(data.frame(df))$factor1)`

Comment: Edited to show that I know what a data frame is.

Answer (score 3):

Using base-R's `tapply` you can do:

```
tapply(factor2, factor1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

what results in

```
A B C 
3 2 1
```

Usind `data.table` you could do it as follows:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[,uniqueN(factor2), factor1]
```

result

```
   factor1 V1
1:       A  3
2:       B  2
3:       C  1
```

Thanks @ytk for the advice on using `uniqueN`

Comment: You can just use `uniqueN` instead of `length(unique(...))`.

Comment: Rather than calculating `unique()` on every group, it might be faster to use `with(unique(df), tapply(factor2, factor1, length))`

Comment: @RichardScriven: True. That might be faster for bigger data-sets. As you have the overhead of `cbind`-ing beforehand => groupwise unique might be faster for small datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `unique` and `table`:

```
table(unique(df)$factor1)    # piped: df %>% unique() %>% `[`('factor1') %>% table()

## A B C 
## 3 2 1
```

Or turn the table into a data.frame if you'd like it in long form:

```
as.data.frame(table(unique(df)$factor1))

##   Var1 Freq
## 1    A    3
## 2    B    2
## 3    C    1
```